# vba in access and conditional formatting of forms

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form that collects different types of data. One of them is the type of document. On accessing the tab the user has to select a type of document, from a pull-down list. If the document is selected as "NDA", then a tab named "type of NDA" must be enabled. The following is the code I am trying to use:

```
 Private Sub doc_AfterUpdate()
    If doc.Value="NDA" then
       tnda.enabled=true
    else
       tnda.enabled=false
    End if
 End Sub
```

The pgm is simple, yet whenever I run my forms it keeps showing "error:type mismatch" and the code stops working.

Thanks for helping me with the above code.
This time i tried the code on a little more complicated form with more options. I tried to disable all the other options and enable them only according to the options i choose(from "type of document" tab in the form).Given below is the code:

```
    Private Sub doc_BeforeUpdate(cancel as integer)
    tnda.enabled=false
    tagr.enabled=false
odoc.enabled=false
    End Sub

    Private Sub doc_AfterUpdate()
    Select Case doc.column(1)
    Case "NDA"
    tnda.enabled=true
    Case "Agreement"
    tagr.enabled=true
    Case "Other"
    odoc.enabled=true
    Case Else
    End Select
    End Sub

    Private Sub doc_Oncurrent()
    Select Case doc.column(1)
    Case "NDA"
    tnda.enabled=true
    Case "Agreement"
    tagr.enabled=true
    Case "Other"
    odoc.enabled=true
    Case Else
    End Select
    End Sub
```

After running the pgm, all my tabs remain disabled irrespective of the choice of doc. Please provide valuable inputs in this regard.
Note tnda:type of NDA
          tagr:type of agreement
            odoc:Other document and doc=type of document  [Find image of my form here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BavdL.png)

Comment: On which line does it stop ? What is the value of doc.value when error happens ?

Comment: It stops in the "IF doc.value="NDA" then" line

Comment: It doesnt seem to work for any value of doc selected from pull down list

Comment: can you attach screenshot of access form? Is the list part of form and what are tabs?

Comment: @malavikanair - how is `doc` declared? Do you have `Option Explicit` on the top of the module?

Comment: @mmehta i cannot attach an image to my question because it says i must earn 10 reputation, i just have one.

Comment: @mmehta yes, the list is part of form. The tabs include type of document(named "doc"), type of nda(named "tnda"), and some11 other tabs.

Comment: @Vityata While designing the form, after having selected "type of document" tab in the form, on the "property sheet" of the combo box->Other option, i have named it as "doc".

Comment: Can you replace `doc.Value` with `Forms("doc").Value`?

Comment: @Vityata thanks! i did it..but its showing error that "it cant find doc referred to in a macro expression or visual basic code"

Comment: @malavikanair - try to put some pictures of your form in the question.

Comment: I have added the link@Vityata

Comment: @vityata hope its useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because Doc is a combobox, thus probably bound to an ID that is numeric.

So either:

```
If doc.Value = <insert value of ID of text "NDA"> then
```

or use the column ID that holds "NDA", most likely the next:

```
If doc.Column(1) = "NDA" then
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Gustav! IT works!!..i tried the 2nd method you suggested. But can you please tell me how i can find the ID of the text?

Comment: Then you must look at the source of the combobox. If that is a field, it is a lookup field, and you must go to the table definition for that info.

Comment: Table definition from "table properties"?

Comment: The field definition in the table for that field. Second tab.

Comment: I checked and data was of text type

Comment: As I see it, doc is a _multi-select combo box_, not a normal one. Using this code will yield unpredictable results because of that

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Thanks! i have changed to single select values. But now i am working on another form and have updated it on my question. Kindly review

Comment: I highly recommend disabling and then enabling on the same event, not different ones. But just step through the code using breakpoints, and you should see what's going on.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth it works if i use `doc.value` instead of `doc.column(1)`